# How to set letter spacing in hint text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-edittext

I have an edit text field, i am able to set letter spacing in edittext normal text, but that letter spacing is not effecting hint text.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etEmailLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etLastNameLayout">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="EMAIL ADDRESS"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white20"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="197dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

this is my style.xml file

```
  <style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <!-- reference our hint & error styles -->
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/ErrorText</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>


        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually might help you: [setLetterSpacing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float))  or XML related attribute android:letterSpacing

Answer (score -1):

android:letterSpacing="1dp"

use this in your xml edittect code you can same use in textview to put more space between character

Answer (score -2):

Use `android:letterSpacing` attribute in `EditText` like below:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="EMAIL ADDRESS"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white20"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="197dp"
            android:letterSpacing="1" /> /*letter spacing*/
```

using `letterSpacing`you can add the spaces in letters.

I hope it work for you.

Comment: This is adding letter spacing to both edit text and hint text, i want to add letter spacing on hint text only